# Issue running Bitrise Codesgindoc with Xcode

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, bitrise

1. I ran bash `-l -c "$(curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitrise-tools/codesigndoc/master/_scripts/install_wrap-xcode.sh)"`
2. Under 'select scheme' A list of apps appeared
3. I selected my app from the list
   3.1 Added location of project

   Open the project: /Users/Jacqueline/Documents/boatconnect/ios/navicotrackapp.xcworkspace
   and Archive, using the Scheme: navicotrackapp
4. I got an error message `exit status 65`
5. open up my error log file
6. I then saw the following message

The following build commands failed:

```
Ld /Users/Jacqueline/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/navicotrackapp-gukdtyixtndirxajfsooveflqxhc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/navicotrackapp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/navicotrackapp.app/navicotrackapp normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you contact Bitrise support via the onsite chat or email? Unfortunately I don't think that without additional information this issue could be solved, but if you contact our support they can guide you through and help you to resolve it! :)

Comment: yeah I did.  I've decided to put bitrise on hold for the moment.  I'm going to do CI with Jenkins and come back to bitrise at a later date

Comment: Got it, though if you have some time I'd still suggest you to contact support as they definitely can guide you through the setup process (and see what we could improve ;) ), and once it's done you won't have to maintain your own Jenkins/CI system :)

Comment: Update. Another team was able to do a successful build on bitrise.  I've already asked them to break down step by step their process.  I honestly don' think it can be that difficult to do.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't - codesigndoc works out of the box **IF** you can Archive the project from Xcode.app ; based on the log you pasted the issue seems to be that Xcode.app itself can't archive it. But without more logs it's really hard to say - our support can help with that ;)